# JAVA drawPolygon() - Parameter Explanation

Tags: java, awt, polygon

I'm currently looking into the `drawPolygon(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int nPoints)` method in Java.
If I am not mistaken, the first two parameters are arrays, indicating the x-coordinates and y-coordinates of the polygon.

My question is, how are the polygon's coordinates interpreted from the two arrays?

For instance, I want to draw a line between the points `(100, 300)` and `(200, 400)`. That is, a line increasing from left to right. 
However, if I put these values into their respective arrays:

```
xPoints = {100, 200}; //x-coordinates 
yPoints = {300, 400}; //y-coordinates
```

I get a line **decreasing** from left to right. As if the points are interpreted `(100, 400)` and `(200, 300)`.

Thus, my question is: how are the array elements evaluated to make up the points of the polygon?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you bother to read the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolygon(int[],%20int[],%20int)) concerning that method? From the Javadoc, this method draws the polygon defined by nPoint line segments, where the first nPoint - 1 line segments are line segments from (xPoints[i - 1], yPoints[i - 1]) to (xPoints[i], yPoints[i]), for 1 ≤ i ≤ nPoints. The figure is automatically closed by drawing a line connecting the final point to the first point, if those points are different.

Comment: @hfontanez That doesn't help to understand why the plot is mirrored, so please reconsider the "Did you bother...?".

Comment: @laune, I have reconsidered my comment, and I stand by it. The Graphics API is well documented. Additionally, even the worst textbook show what the OP selected as "the answer".

Comment: @hfontanez You wrote "bother to read the Javadoc concerning *that method*." (Emphasis is mine.) And you continue "this method draws..." etc. There is one short sentence in the API describing how the user coordinate space is initially defined (and it's far from this API), and not having read this or a textbook on computer graphics is - compared what else is not known here on SO - a very minor misdemeanour.

Comment: @laune since you feel you are the spoke person for the OP, let me clarify this for you. The posted question was: "how are the array elements evaluated to make up the points of the polygon?" The method's API answers that question, and it is in the extract I provided in my first answer. So yes, a little research on the OP's part would have answer it. The problem is that SO is becoming more and more a place where people who doesn't feel like researching a topic could come to get answers because there plenty of enablers around. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinate system has origo in the top-left corner, and the y-axis increasing downwards.

[image]

This is why you get a downward slope when you *increase* the *y*-coordinate.

Answer (score 2):

The default coordinate system has the origin in the upper left hand side corner of the canvas, and the y values *increase* from the top of the screen downwards. You can use an affine transform if you aren't happy with this orientation.

This is an *example* (!) from some code I have lying around - you may have to adapt it according to your situation:

```
// Polygon -> PathIterator -> Path2D, and then:
Path2D path = ...;
at.scale( 1, -1 );
path.transform( at );
bbox = path.getBounds2D();
at = new AffineTransform();
at.translate( -bbox.getMinX(), -bbox.getMinY() );
path.transform( at );
```